# Strange deformation when apply "Realize instance" Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

When I realize my instances, they don't look deformed.

Here are my instances without realization.

[image]

Here are my instances when realized

[image]

And here is my node setup (here with Realize Instance node unplugged but at the position I plug it after)

[image]

What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z coordinate here is too big, which cause [floating point precision error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation)

Then you realize instances faces converted from instance space to object space, which means add -828276... number to Z coordinate of each point inside instance.

But floats may handle a limited number of digits. For example, if it was
1.0012 adding -828276000 will cut off .0012, because it is too many digits to handle for float:

[image]

As result all numbers like 1.0012, 0.9992 1.0034 will clue together at -828276000 position

[image]

To fix this, your objects have to be closer to center.

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you a lot for your answer and the "under the hood" explanation